# Why is VBA Marco cannot import file that with out type file?

Tags: excel, vba

> I need to import all type file and fix length with thic code, Pls help me
> all How to fix an issue on Excel 2016 type files with VBA with this code

```
Sub Import_SD2()
    filePath = "D:\Project\Re\INPUT\SD.txt"
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SD") 
   
    wsTarget.Range("A3:XY5000").ClearContents
    lastRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
            fileContent = .ReadAll
            .Close
    End With

rows = Split(fileContent, vbCrLf)
 For rowNum = 2 To UBound(rows) + 1

            Dim textline As String ' Declare textline variable

            textline = rows(rowNum - 1) 

             wsTarget.Cells(lastRow + rowNum, 1) = Trim(Mid(textline, 1, 4)) 


            totalRows = totalRows + 1

        Next rowNum

        lastRow = lastRow + UBound(rows)

    wsTarget.UsedRange.columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us the error you are experiencing.  Also, tell us the  line on which the error occurs.

Comment: Error:: With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
            fileContent = .ReadAll
            .Close
    End With.  <==I cannot import text files to excel

Comment: "Error:" *some specific error*, or does it literally say only "Error" ?

Comment: There's quite a lot of unsafe assumptions in your code.  Please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and check the code inspections.  You will learn a lot about how to more correctly write VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a complete answer but this is the code I use to get a text file as an array of strings

```
Public Function GetFileAsArrayOfStrings(ByVal ipFilePath As String, Optional ByRef ipSplitAtToken As String = vbCrLf) As Variant

    Dim myFso  As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set myFso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        
    GetFileAsArrayOfStrings = VBA.Split(myFso.OpenTextFile(ipFilePath, ForReading).ReadAll, ipSplitAtToken)
   
        
End Function
```